# How to Create tables in mysql accounting for multiple constraints at a time?

Tags: mysql

I've bolded (**) primary keys and foreign keys are in italic (***). No foreign keys are allowed to be null.

Relational Scheme:

```
TrainingSession(**date**, **time**, ***buildingName***, ***roomNum***, *studentId*, *empId*)
```

Whilst it holds true to these constraints

```
Unique Constraints: TrainingSession
• (date, time, studentId)
• (date, time, empId)

CREATE TABLE TrainingSession ( 
    date        DATE    (DD/MM/YYYY)    
    time        TIME    (HH:MM:SS)   
    buildingName    VARCHAR(25)     
    roomNum     CHAR(4)          
    studentId   CHAR(4)         
    empId           CHAR(4)
    PRIMARY KEY (date, time, buildingName, roomNum)
);
```

I know it is wrong and incomplete but when it comes to more than one type of constraint multiple times I get very confused. Please help!!!!

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Essentially the code I put is to somewhat describe what I'm going for. But I'm basically asking what sql code I'm supposed to write to: Create a table - TrainingSession - where date, time, buildingName and roomNum are PRIMARY KEYS as well as buildingName, roomNum, studentId and empId are FOREIGN KEYS.

Comment: Are you asking the syntax for a `CREATE TABLE` statement? You can look at this 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html for that. For foreign keys, you need to define the other tables where they will be linked to as well and then you can use the foreign key syntax in the same link.